# Ubuntu 20.04.2 doesn't shutdown!

Tags: boot, 20.04, shutdown

I have installed the 20.04.2 yesterday. When I tried to turn off the system yesterday, it went to a black screen with an underline blinking on the top left. After 30 seconds or so 3 lines of text flashed and then the computer shut off.
I tried turning it on and then off again and same thing happened.
But it was too fast for me to read what the lines said and I was busy so I just didn't do anything about it.
Today after I finished working, I tried to turn the computer off and it's been in the ASUS logo screen (with ubuntu logo underneath) for 10 minutes now.
It doesn't turn off.
What should I do?

Comment: Press and hold the power bottom for a couple of seconds. Maybe this helps to force shut down the PC. Then start again and see the problem is still there.

Comment: Wouldn't it create problems? Because from what I know, Ubuntu doesnt really like being forced to shut down! Actually the reason why I reinstalled my ubuntu was because I forced the last one to shut down!

Comment: No, it  shouldn't  hurt. Sometime there are some pending processes that can be killed  by force shut down.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some services waited to be closed.
You can make GRUB to print some information.
`sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

Edit that line like this.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

then,`sudo update-grub`.

reboot, you can check which service is preventing your reboot.

PS, I guess the service maybe **snapd**, a package manager made by Ubuntu.

To remove snap store, check this

https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-04/